# Using ntpd to perform a one-time sync to an NTP server is taking too long

Tags: ntp, ntpd

I have several servers that need to be sync'd to an NTP server on my network.

Initially, the time on these servers is relatively close (+/- 5 seconds). My goal is to do a "one-time sync" for each server so that the time is closer to that which is provided by the NTP server, and then start the NTP daemon so that synchronicity can be maintained:

```
ntpd -gq
/etc/init.d/ntpd start
```

My issue is that `ntpd -gq` is taking quite a while to set the time. I've let it go on for 15-20 minutes and it still hasn't completed. It pauses after printing these messages:

```
[root:~] ntpd -gq                                                                        
29 Oct 23:32:50 ntpd[10893367]: ntpd 4.2.8p13+vmware@1.3847-o Mon May 20 19:29:19 UTC 2019 (1): Starting
29 Oct 23:32:50 ntpd[10893367]: Command line: ntpd -gq                                                  
29 Oct 23:32:50 ntpd[10893367]: proto: precision = 0.403 usec (-21)                                     
29 Oct 23:32:50 ntpd[10893367]: basedate set to 2019-05-08                                              
29 Oct 23:32:50 ntpd[10893367]: gps base set to 2019-05-12 (week 2053)                                  
29 Oct 23:32:50 ntpd[10893367]: Listen and drop on 0 v6wildcard [::]:123                                
29 Oct 23:32:50 ntpd[10893367]: Listen and drop on 1 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0:123                             
29 Oct 23:32:50 ntpd[10893367]: Listen normally on 2 lo0 127.0.0.1:123                                  
29 Oct 23:32:50 ntpd[10893367]: Listen normally on 3 vmk0 10.223.83.233:123                             
29 Oct 23:32:50 ntpd[10893367]: Listen normally on 4 vmk1 192.168.88.11:123                             
29 Oct 23:32:50 ntpd[10893367]: Listen normally on 5 vmk2 192.168.92.1:123                              
29 Oct 23:32:50 ntpd[10893367]: Listen normally on 6 vmk9 169.254.9.2:123                               
29 Oct 23:32:50 ntpd[10893367]: Listen normally on 7 vmk3 169.254.0.2:123                               
29 Oct 23:32:50 ntpd[10893367]: Listen normally on 8 lo0 [::1]:123                                      
29 Oct 23:32:50 ntpd[10893367]: Listen normally on 9 lo0 [fe80::1%1]:123                                
29 Oct 23:32:50 ntpd[10893367]: Listen normally on 10 vmk0 [fe80::b226:28ff:fe31:2b00%2]:123            
29 Oct 23:32:50 ntpd[10893367]: Listen normally on 11 vmk0 [2620:145:c00:402a:b226:28ff:fe31:2b00]:123  
29 Oct 23:32:50 ntpd[10893367]: Listen normally on 12 vmk1 [fe80::250:56ff:fe6a:2e2c%3]:123             
29 Oct 23:32:50 ntpd[10893367]: Listen normally on 13 vmk2 [fe80::250:56ff:fe6d:f624%4]:123             
29 Oct 23:32:50 ntpd[10893367]: Listen normally on 14 vmk9 [fe80::250:56ff:fe63:e2c1%5]:123             
29 Oct 23:32:50 ntpd[10893367]: Listen normally on 15 vmk3 [fe80::250:56ff:fe66:cd16%6]:123
```

Perhaps I have a lack of understanding of NTP, but I would imagine that fetching a time from a remote server and setting it locally would not take this long. I did read that gradually adjusting the time is intended functionality as not to disrupt the flow of running processes; is this true and is there a way to bypass it?

Also, using `ntpdate` is not possible in my environment, although it shouldn't matter since this is deprecated.